# SQL Query to find Parent records without child records.Both child and parent records are on the same table

Tags: sql, parent-child

I need a SQL Query to find Parent records without having any child records.Both child and parent records are on the same table

Comment: multi-level depths (the parent of 1 can have another parent which can have another parent...) or single level?

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SELF JOIN` on the table as follows would give the parents without children.

```
-- relations (record_id, parent_id)
SELECT parents.record_id 
FROM 
    relations parents
    LEFT JOIN relations children
    ON parents.record_id = children.parent_id
WHERE 
    children.record_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming: "mytable" is your table, parent_id is a reference to the parent's PK, top level parents have a null parent_id:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM mytable WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM Nodes N
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Nodes WHERE Nodes.ParentID = N.ID)
```